# Using .onresize to control text on responsive video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, onresize

I'm trying to control the size of the text used to show elapsed and total time of a video player. I am currently controlling the play/pause/sound and full screen icons, but can't access the time display. Below is the javascript used to resize the controls on window resize:

```
window.onload = function() {
resize();
}

window.onresize = function() {
resize();
}

function resize() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('play')[0].style.width = (document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0].offsetHeight * .25) + 'px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('fullscreen')[0].style.width = (document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0].offsetHeight * .25) + 'px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('mute')[0].style.width = (document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0].offsetHeight * .25) + 'px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('time-played')[0].style.width = (document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0].offsetHeight * .25) + 'px';
}
```

Also trying to figure out the best way to minimize and simplify this using jQuery(to consolidate all of the classes into one array, similar to:

```
$('.play .fullscreen .mute .time-played')
```

My current implementation: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/1/)

Comment: Have you considered using CSS's [@media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to achieve the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use jQuery, then you can run the resize method on [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and add window [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) bindings as well, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // resize on dom ready
    resizePlayer();

    // add window resize binding
    $(window).resize(resizePlayer);
});
```

To combine selectors in jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('.play, .fullscreen, .mute, .time-played')
```

So, your resize method can now look something like this:

```
function resizePlayer() {
    // Set your width to whatever you want...
    // this is just a rough translation of your method above
    var newWidth = $('.timeline').outerHeight() * 0.25;

    $('.play, .fullscreen, .mute, .time-played').width(newWidth);
}
```

Comment: @royhowie true! I'll update the answer to simplify it for this use case.

Comment: This is how I imagined it would work, thanks! Any suggestion on the second part of my question, regarding resizing the text to conform to the rest of the button sizes?